# How to use this dictionary to show the file information in template in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this that I have passed to template in Django:

```
files = {
    "20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt": [645045714, 2584.9807732105255, 137625600], 
    "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt": [645045714, 2569.1707730293274, 158859264]
}
```

The key is the file_name and the value is the array. The first element in array consist of `total_file_size, second_element -> duration` the file transfer has started and `third element -> number of size transferred`.

I am listing the file information in table along with the remPercentage and remTime to transfer the file.

```
  {% for choice in overview %}              
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice_stop" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" onchange="checkChecked_stop()"/></td>
            <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.name }}</label></td>
            <td>{{ choice.source }}</td>
            <td><div id="remPercentage{{ forloop.counter }}"></div></td>
            <td>{{ choice.start_date }}</td>
            <td><div id="remTime{{ forloop.counter }}"></div></td>
            <td>{{ choice.human_size }}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  disabled {{ choice.flag_email }} /></td>
        </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Here's my Javascript function called changeData() that is hitting the server and getting the `remPercentage` and `remTime`.

```
var interval;

var counter=0;
var length;
var speed;
var duration;

function changeData() {
    var url="/ajax_call_size";
    var xmlh=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlh.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlh.send(null);
    var resObj=xmlh.responseText;

    var total_size = get the total_size
    var transfer_duration = get the transfer_duration
    var transfer_size = get the transfer_size
    length=total_size.length;
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++) {

        if(typeof(transfer_size[i])!="undefined") {
            transfer_per = parseInt(100-(transfer_size[i]/total_size[i] * 100));
            remaining_size =  total_size[i] -  transfer_size[i];

            if(transfer_per!=0) {
               eTime_remaining = (transfer_duration[i]/transfer_size[i])*(total_size[i]-transfer_size[i]) ;  
               document.getElementById("remPercentage"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML=transfer_per+"%";;
               document.getElementById("remTime"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML=secondsToString(eTime_remaining);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("remPercentage"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML="1%";
               document.getElementById("remTime"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML="1 sec";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("remPercentage"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML="completed";
            document.getElementById("remTime"+parseInt(i+1)).innerHTML="completed";
        } 
    }
    counter+=1;
}

setInterval("changeData()",5000);
```

How can I extract the dictionary data and put the information in respective file coloumn in template? Thanks

Comment: why dont you get the rendered template from server using ajax call ..

Comment: Yes I use ajax call to get the information from the server every 5 seconds.

Comment: yes right ..  so what you have to do is instead to get response in json(or some other format) ... in response give the html ..  like `def view(request):if request.is_ajax():return render('ajax_template.html', locals())` .. and in ajax success function replace the html with the response html so this is how you can render your data at backend on server side only .. where your ajax_template is the template code you have written above ..

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call :
say your `ajax_template.html` :

```
{% for choice in overview %}

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice_stop" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" onchange="checkChecked_stop()"/></td>
        <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.name }}</label></td>
        <td>{{ choice.source }}</td>
        <td><div id="remPercentage{{ forloop.counter }}"></div></td>
        <td>{{ choice.start_date }}</td>
        <td><div id="remTime{{ forloop.counter }}"></div></td>
        <td>{{ choice.human_size }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  disabled {{ choice.flag_email }} /></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

and your view is :

```
def view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
         # this view get called at '/view/' url 
         #do your calculations here instead in javascript function
         # in case your fetching some variables from client side then send them in POST or GET .. 
         return render('ajax_template', locals())
```

Now in ajax do this :

```
$.ajax({
      url:'/view/',
      success:function(result){
          $('#div').html('').html(result)
 }})
```

where your $('#div') is html div in template where you want to render the result

Comment: `$("#div").load("/view/")` ?

Comment: $("#div").load("/view/") is wrong i think .. i should be $("#div").load(#some procedure)

Comment: You can handler the response, but the jquery doc says: **Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.**